# os.getenv returns None instead correct value

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, getenv

I have a complex piece of software I am not able to post, nor do I have a concrete working example. I will try to explain the problem, maybe someone encountered this before.

On the Linux shell I have defined an environment variable:

```
> export MY_TEST_ENV=4711
> echo $MY_TEST_ENV
> 4711
```

Within the complex code I want to obtain this variable with

```
print os.getenv('MY_TEST_ENV')
```

which always returns `None`. If I create a test-script to test this behavior, even with classes in different files, I always get the desired behavior, e.g., `os.getenv('MY_TEST_ENV')` returns the correct value `4711`.

The code is started with `sudo`.

Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: How are you running this "complex code"?

Comment: Are the rest of the environment variables still there? How is the python process launched? If you start a process with the `execve` system call and do _not_ fill in the environment variable, the child's environment is zeroed.

Comment: I knew the solution to my problem is trivial - because I run the python process as sudo!  But I have not seen this solution until I was asked o how to run the code. Without sudo, I see the variable (but the rest of the code will not work, though).

Comment: @Alex Remember that `sudo` starts a new shell with superuser privileges, and scrubs the environment according to the security policy. Using the `-E` (or `--preserve-env`) switch to `sudo` *may* cause `MY_TEST_ENV` to be retained, or maybe not again depending on the specifics of your system's security policy. Another route is to request someone with appropriate access to the system to inject the variable you want into root's environment by editing the appropriate initialization script.

Answer (score 12):

Most likely the way you invoke the Python process makes you lose the environment. If you export the variable within a running shell and, directly after that, invoke the Python process in question in the same shell, this environment variable should definitely be available to this Python process. To help you debugging this issue: instead of the code in question (`print os.getenv('my...')`), print the whole environment via `print os.environ`. From the result you should be able to infer what happened to your environment.